# Can I status override an auto renewing membership?

Tags: civimember

A client wants to status override a recurring membership but cannot do so.

Here are a couple of membership edit screens:

The first is for a membership that ***is*** auto renew and has an associated recurring contribution:

[image: auto renew]

The second is for a membership that ***is not*** auto renew and does not have an associated recurring contribution:

[image: not auto renew]

It seems that for some reason, we don't allow people to status override recurring memberships.

Can anyone shed any light on why this is not possible?

Is there a business case for it being set up in this way.

I did have a look at the code but nothing obvious jumped out at me. I'm guessing someone out there knows the thinking behhind this.

Comment: In the first image there is text indicating 'Over-ride end date'. This suggests to me that this membership has already been overridden, and for some reason the form is not allowing you to change the override. A different random thought: have you configured your Probation custom Membership Status in some odd way that is causing an issue?

Comment: I can imagine a concern with being able to process membership status changes properly on receiving payment perhaps led to a poor choice to decide supporting these overrides was out of scope. Getting the tests to all work, and to ignore changing the membership status while still renewing a membership does seem like a bunch of special case statements.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to have been implemented as a deliberate 'feature' to prevent users from making changes to memberships linked to recurring payments. See this related question for details:

[How can you edit the end date for an auto-renew membership?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/31215/how-can-you-edit-the-end-date-for-an-auto-renew-membership)

A fix has been merged into CiviCRM core ([PR #15540](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/15540)) that fixes this issue for the end date field. This fix should be included in CiviCRM 5.20.